# Aggregating text in r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have the following data frame.

```
x <- data.frame("Item" = c('Item1','Item1','Item2','Item2'), "Name" = c("This row and","the next should be grouped together","Also this row and","the next should be grouped together"))
```

I want the output to be as follows.

```
x2 <- data.frame("Item" = c('Item1','Item2'), "Name" = c("This row and the 
next should be grouped together","Also this row and the next should be 
grouped together"))
```

I have a large data-frame of 10000 rows and I am new to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and group your `Item` variable and concatenate the text. I collapsed by an empty string but ', ' or ';' would be also possible

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarise(Name=paste0(Name, collapse=''))
```